# Why is my R code for filtering data producing different results with "fread()" and "ffdf()"?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, ff

I have a huge file with 7 million records and 160 variables. I came to know that fread() and read.csv.ffdf() are two ways to handle such big data. But when I try to use dplyr to filter these two data sets, I get different results. Below is a small subset of my data-

```
 sample_data
AGE AGE_NEONATE AMONTH AWEEKEND
2   18                  5        0
3   32                 11        0
4   67                  7        0
5   37                  6        1
6   57                  5        0
7   50                  6        0
8   59                 12        0
9   44                  9        0
10  40                  9        0
11  27                  3        0
12  59                  8        0
13  44                  7        0
14  81                 10        0
15  59                  6        1
16  32                 10        0
17  90                 12        1
18  69                  7        0
19  62                 11        1
20  85                  6        1
21  43                 10        0
```

Code1

```
sample_data <- fread("/user/sample_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
age_filter<-sample_data%>%filter(!(is.na(AGE)), between(as.numeric(AGE),65 , 95))
```

Result1-

```
AGE AGE_NEONATE AMONTH AWEEKEND
1  67          NA      7        0
2  81          NA     10        0
3  90          NA     12        1
4  69          NA      7        0
5  85          NA      6        1
```

Code2-

```
sample_data <- read.csv.ffdf(file="C:/Users/sample_data.csv", header=F ,fill=T)
header.true <- function(df) {
      names(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
      df[-1,]
      }
sample_data<-tbl_ffdf(sample_data)
sample_data<-header.true(sample_data)
age_filter<-sample_data%>%filter(!(is.na(AGE)), between(as.numeric(AGE),65 , 95))
```

Result2-

```
AGE AGE_NEONATE AMONTH AWEEKEND
1  81                 10        0
2  90                 12        1
3  85                  6        1
```

I know that my 1st code is correct and gives me the correct results. What am I doing wrong in the 2nd code?

Comment: What happens if you run example 1 with stringsAsFactors = F?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really tried running your code, but from what I can see, I suspect the following:

In your 2nd code version, you are reading the headers as part of the data. This leads to all the columns being imported as `character` rather than `numeric`.
In addition, most likely you have `default.stringsAsFactors()` returning `TRUE`, meaning that the imported character columns are treated as `factors`.

Now I guess that your `between` is being applied to factor levels between 65 and 95, rather than to the actual numbers. Since you probably don't have data for every year (age), 67 and 69 are likely mapped to factor levels below 65 (i.e. `as.numeric(AGE)` will return you the factor levels the numbers map to, and not the numbers as you see them when printing).

Try to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or convert explicitly to character after reading.